# Can programs written via Visual Studio 2019 be compatible on all Windows 10 versions, or only on recent versions of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, visual-studio-2019

Imagine you have a program written with the latest supported standards in mind, and compiled with the latest compiler version. In this case, the compiler version that comes with Visual Studio 2019 is MSVC v142.

Then imagine some programs that refuse to run on older versions of Windows 10 (like 1507 or 1511).

Can a program that is written via Visual Studio 2019 run on any version of Windows 10 (including out of support versions), or only the most recent versions of Windows 10 (currently 1803 and 1809)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what APIs you use, but you can generally build Win32 desktop applications for older version of Windows with the current Windows SDK and Visual Studio. Officially the VS 2019 Redist [System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements) support Windows 10 (Version 1703; build 15063) or higher and the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC, as well as older versions of Windows.

For UWP apps, it depends on both what APIs you use and the 'minimum Windows target' version you set.

Generally Windows 10 (Version 1607; build 14393) is the oldest one you are likely to ever encounter outside of enterprise settings.

Comment: Windows 10 v1607 with the SDK version 10.0.14393.0 is the last version used on some Lumia phones. But The support for windows 10 Mobile will end after December 11, 2019.
SDK's before 10.0.16299.0 are not available in a clean install of VS2019. But they can be targeted when installed with VS20173